# Top logical level of the module’s body

Tags: python, module

I did not understand this sentence:

"For clarity and cleanliness of your code, be wary about doing anything else in the top logical level of the module’s body except binding the module’s attributes."

Can someone explain it and give an example.

Comment: Where are you quoting from?

Comment: It means any low level logic should be implemented at the module level, and the top level should just put the pieces together and not get bothered with implementation details. Because boilerplate matters

Comment: Take a look at a big module like [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy) 99.9% of the code is not in the top level. it is basically just an `__init__.py` that collects all the different submodules together. That way it is easier to locate specific parts of the module when browsing the source code